# merge columns of two dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

How can two dataframes be quickly merged? 
dataframes

```
df1<-data.frame(a=(1:5),b=(1:5))
df2<-data.frame(c=(1:5),d=(1:5))
```

intended output:

```
output<-data.frame(a=(1:5),b=(1:5),c=(1:5),d=(1:5))
```

Comment: using `cbind()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this by using other function like

```
cbind.data.frame(df1,df2)
  a b c d
1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5
```

or

```
cbind2(df1,df2)
  a b c d
1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5
```

Comment: These are not "*other functions*". `cbind.data.frame` is a `data.frame` *method* that is being automatically called by `cbind` upon a `data.frame` input. `cbind2` is also called by `cbind` if certain conditions were met. This answer is more confusing than helpful IMO. OP just needs to read `?cbind`